# how do I stop the div areas from moving?

Tags: html, css

I relatively new to html and css and wanted to code my own website.
When I hover over the div areas, the whole website beneath them moves a bit and I don't know how to fix it.

I tried moving the div areas when I hover over them to fix it but it didn't work.

```css
Html {
  /*max-width:75%;*/
  font-family: "Arial Black";
}

div {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.film {
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  /*unteres zum zentrieren des Textes*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* Horizontal zentrieren */
  align-items: center;
  /* Vertikal zentrieren */
}

.film:hover {
  border-right: 5px solid black;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  position: relative;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
}

.buch {
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  float: right;
}

.buch:hover {
  border-right: 5px solid black;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  position: relative;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
}

.games {
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  clear: right;
}

.games:hover {
  border-right: 5px solid black;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  position: relative;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
}

.portfolio {
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  float: right;
}

.blog {
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  clear: right;
}

p {
  font-size: 45px;
  line-height: 80%;
}

.hallo {}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container2 {
  border: 3px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  /*margin-left:150px; gleiche px wie div width*/
  margin-left: 240px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  /*font-family:Arial;*/
}

a:visited {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <style>
    @import url("CSS_2.css");
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="">
      <div class="film">
        <p>MOVIES</p>
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class="container2">
      <p href="" style="line-height:100%">Hello</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="">
    <div class="buch">
      <p>BOOKS</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="games">
    <p>GAMES</p>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio">
    <p <!--style="font-size:65px" -->PORTFOLIO</p>
  </div>
  <div class="blog">
    <p>BLOG</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The boxes are moving because you go from a 3px border to a 5px border, thus they take in more space. You'll need to account for that extra space when you hover over them

Comment: There are many things wrong with your code which leads me to the conclusion that you start to learn from the wrong resources. Using float to align items is never a good idea. Also very repetitive code. It will cause you to learn bad habits which will throw you off-track. If you're interested in learning how to do it right you can get in contact with me (I'm from Germany too).

Comment: @tacoshy yeah as I said im just starting with html and css but it would be cool if you could name some sites where I can use html and css in practice to learn it with examples im coding.

Comment: One really good book in German that teaches you nearly everything you need to know is "HTML5 und CSS3 - Das umfassende Handbuch" (ISBN: 987-3-8362-6226-2). Good youtube videos you mostly find in English such as [FreeCodeCamp.org](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kUMe1FH4CHE). I would recommend you to stay away from the channel "Programmieren lernen" and the website w3school. Good CSS toolsets are [Flexbox Guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and [Grid Guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Answer (score -2):

Check css property [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing). You should add `box-sizing: border-box` to the divs with borders.